# Error in enabling cors in spring boot app (React Frontend)

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, cors, backend

I am making a basic contact app with backend in spring boot and frontend is react js
On api calling from react, i am getting cors error

```
const resp = await axios.post(
  "url",
  data,
  {
    headers: {
      // "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  }
);
```

[image]

I have handled the cores and enabled them in my backend but still getting this issue
**Backend Code**

**Global Cors config**

[image]
**Controller cors**

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")
```

> GIT HUB LINK
> https://github.com/bhutianimukul/contacts

**WEB Security Configuration**
[web Security github](https://github.com/bhutianimukul/contacts/blob/master/src/main/java/com/project/contacts/contacts/security/WebSecurityConfiguration.java)

Comment: Have you tried adding `@EnableWebMvc` annotation to your `WebConfig` class?

Comment: yes i tried that also but that was not working

Comment: still getting Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://contact-spring.herokuapp.com/users/signin' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Answer (score -1):

Look this article and try again https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/

Or If you set global cors config try other way like this:
remove WebConfig class and @CorsOrigin annotation and add this code

```
@Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000");
            }
        };
    }
```

To ContactsApplication.java class

Or you can use OncePerRequestFilter class

Comment: But the webconfig file is also doing the same thing and also i dont want this cors to be enabled for localhost :3000 only, thats why i put * to accept all incoming request origin